# Change Comment Font in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

In the official [knitr manual](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/manual/), comments are in green and they are upright as opposed to italic. But whenever I use knitr to compile a PDF, my comments are purple and italic. How can I change this?

Comment: Have a look at `knit_theme`

Comment: (1) it would probably be better to give the answer as an answer to your own question, rather than editing your question; (2) [a comment on your closed "why do I get low resolution" question, which I can't leave there]: feel free to edit (undelete/ask a new question) with more information rather than closing -- if it turns out that this is a commonly encountered situation, the answers could be helpful to future readers as well as to yourself.  I suspect you're sending your output to a PNG file with relatively low resolution, but I can't tell without more information.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker , I've done as you suggested. I'll post my other question soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Thanks to mnel for the tip. Just use `knit_theme`: you use the `knit_theme` command within the R Sweave document, similar to the way in which you put in code chunks.

E.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{article}    # Setting document class

<<adjust-preamble, include=FALSE>>=            # Using knit_theme
knit_theme$set("seashell")
@

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}

etc.
```